# Java - Aplicativo bloqueado pela segurança do java

Tags: java, javafx

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação JavaFX utilizando Intellij, ao executar na ide tudo ocorre muito bem, mas ao abrir o arquivo .JNLP me deparo com a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Estou utilizando o java 8 para a aplicação mais precisamente a versão 1.8.0_202, o que esta causando isso e como corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

Isto é padrão do JavaVM, é possível desabilitar a segurança, mas eu não recomendaria. Você provavelmente também está usando solicitações de todas permissões sem precisar, ou realmente sua JavaVM está com nível restrito e nem **sandbox** funcionaria totalmente (NÃO RESOLVE):

```
<security>
    <sandbox />
</security>
```

mas é uma questão de segurança, o que creio que resolveria talvez seria assinar o teu programa, os passos são:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/signed_jnlp.html#A1148052
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Ou seja, não deve assinar o jnlp, deve colocar o jnlp dentro de um jar a assinar o jar. algo como:

```
jarsigner <seu jar>.jar alias
```

Os detalhes estão nos links acima